# error: redefinition of class when two classes with header files are defined

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a tutorial. In which two classes are defined with two .h files and two .cpp files. The code is given below. I don't know why it is giving me error?

class birthday is working fine but when I add class People and class Birthday is used in class People then it gives me error.
I double check from some of the posts of redefinition error like including guard etc those things are Ok in my code.
I am using these lines to compile and run code in visual studio code.

```
g++ -c People.cpp -o People.o
g++ -c Birthday.cpp -o Birthday.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++  main.o Birthday.o -o prog
./prog

#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BITHDAY_H
using namespace std;
class Birthday
{
    public:
    Birthday(int d, int m, int y );
    void printdate();
    private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

};
#endif

#include "Birthday.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Birthday::Birthday(int m, int d, int y)
{
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}
void Birthday:: printdate()
{
    cout << day <<"/" << month << "/" << year <<endl; 
}

#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H
#include "Birthday.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class People
{
public:
    People(string x, Birthday bo);
    void printinfo();
private:
    string name;
    Birthday dateofbirth;
};
#endif

#include "People.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"
using namespace std;

People::People(string x, Birthday bo)
:
name  (x),
dateofbirth(bo)
{
}
void People::printinfo()
{
    cout << name << "was born on " <<endl;
    cout <<  "Birthday is :";
    dateofbirth.printdate();
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"
#include "People.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Birthday birthobj(12,5,1995);
    birthobj.printdate();
    People Peoplename("Muhammad Adil", birthobj);
    Peoplename.printinfo();
}
```

Comment: youre define does *not* match the ifndef (`#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H #define BITHDAY_H`) notice the missing r in the define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not defining the header guard correctly.

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BITHDAY_H
```

should be

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `#pragma once` would be better as it avoids typos like this.

Comment: It also avoids portability.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame its not standard

Comment: It's not standard because it can't be made to work correctly in some environments.

Answer (score 0):

`Header Guards` is required to resolve the redefinition issue as mentioned by you.

[Header Guards - Source File Inclusion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)

Your `Birthday` class header file should be in `Header Guard` as below:

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H
using namespace std;
class Birthday
{
    public:
       Birthday(int d, int m, int y );
       void printdate();
    private:
       int day;
       int month;
       int year;

 };
 #endif
```

As can be seen above in code:

Incorrect line `#define BITHDAY_H` is changed to `#define BIRTHDAY_H`

So, it seems everything else is correct in your code apart from above typo error.

I hope it helps!